# Python indentation mystery

Tags: python, loops, enter

Why am I getting the following error? The last `print` statement should not be a part of the `while` loop.

```
>>> while n>= 0:
...     n = n-1
...     print(n)
... print ("TO A!!")
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    print ("TO A!!")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: @KasraAD That isn't the cause of the issue though, its still valid syntax.

Comment: @KasraAD that's how the interpreter shows it - `'... '` is the continuation prompt

Comment: yep ,i just miss that its in terminal :D

Comment: @Juergen, the space doesn't affect the statement. Both, print("string") and print ("string") will work. The answer is actually related to what someone mentioned down bellow. On the shell, you can only run one block at a time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to press <kbd>enter</kbd> after your `while` loop to exit from the loop

```
>>> n = 3
>>> while n>=0:
...     n = n-1
...     print (n)
...                         # Press enter here
2
1
0
-1
>>> print ("To A!!")
To A!!
```

Note:- `...` implies that you are still in the `while` block

Comment: This would work certainly but it's not the answer that I'm looking for. If I press enter as suggested it will execute the loop and then the next print would be a new statement. The question I guess should be, how do I add an extra statement after a loop on the terminal before executing the loop?

Comment: @ViniciusSantana put that within a method and run it, I don't think the python shell supports that..

Comment: You guys were right. Python shell can only run one block per execution.

Answer (score 4):

The default python shell works OK for typing but it really does not understand pasting from clipboard. The real solution is to install `ipython`, which is an advanced shell for python with many niceties:

```
% ipython3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:08:17) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: n = 5

In [2]: while n >= 0:
   ...:     n = n-1
   ...:     print(n)
   ...: print ("TO A!!")
   ...: 
4
3
2
1
0
-1
TO A!!

In [3]:
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess that the error shows up because python shell don't support that. It want you to do one thing in a time.! I do the same things in my python 2.7 shell and it said:

```
File "<pyshell#4>", line 4
    print 'to all'
                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

when I do the same thing in my python 3.4 shell, it said: `unexpected indent.`